# C - Swapping nodes in a linked list with a sorting algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, list, sorting, linked-list

Im working on a project for school in which I need to sort a linked list with any sorting algorithm (preferably bubble) - please note that swapping each node data is not allowd as I am expected to swap the nodes. I can not paste all the code of my project as it is very wide and it is in Spanish, reason for which I will show you the parts in which I try to implement the node swapping.

To sum up, the project itself is quite simple, a linked list where each node contains information of a person (name, last name, age, etc).

I have to sort the list alphabetically. Please, bear in mind that I cannot implement the sorting nor the swapping algorithms in functions (That is to say, I cannot make a 'swapNodes' function and them implement it in the code.

I managed to swap two nodes following this logic:

```
firstNode = auxiliar->next;
auxiliar-> next = firstNode->next;
firstNode->next = auxiliar;
```

This works to swap 2 nodes perfectly.

Problem is when I have to implement this logic with a sorting algorithm in order for it to sort all the list, and this is where I need you guys to help me.

I have checked every post about bubblesorting and node swapping but I just can get it working.

My  professor tried to help me, implementing my node swapping code in the following way (please note that as an example, the following code should sorts by age):

```
while (flag == 1) {
        auxiliar = firstNode;
        flag = 0;

        if (auxiliar->edad > auxiliarSiguiente->edad) {

              firstNode = auxiliar->next;
              auxiliar-> next = firstNode->next;
              firstNode->next = auxiliar;
              flag = 1;

        }

        auxiliar3 = firstNode;

        while (auxiliar->next != NULL ) {

            if (auxiliar->age > auxiliarNext->age) {

                auxiliar2 = auxiliar->next;
                auxiliar->next = auxiliar2->next;
                auxiliar2->next = auxiliar;
                auxiliar3->next = auxiliar2;

            } else {
                auxiliar = auxiliar->next;
            }

            auxiliar3 = auxiliar3->next;

        }

    }
```

And then again, this code works just fine when there are 2 nodes. In case there are more, it does not sort in a correct way. Moreover, Im not quite sure which sorting algorithm my professor used.

Perhaps what my teacher did is wrong, or maybe there is a simpler way to do it.

I greatly appreciate your feedback, as I could not manage to find a way to solve it myself.

Hope you guys can help me!

Comment: you should consider having a doubly linked list, if not you can´t swap/insert/remove current node, just node after

Comment: I am not allowed to use a doubly linked list

Answer (score 1):

Your original swap code does not alter the `next` pointer of the node that *pointed* to the node `auxiliar` pointed to before the swap (which there will be if `auxiliar` isn't the first node in the list).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Scott! If I did not do anything wrong, I alter the next pointer of the node previous to auxiliar (considering it is not the first node) at the last part of the code (forgot to indicate that is the reason for which auxiliar 2 and 3 exist, both of which are initialized pointing to the first node)

Comment: If you can, verify that your swap code works; if it doesn't, there isn't much point in going further.  (It would be easier if it were its own function; you could write it that way during development, then "unroll" it for final submission.)  Once that is done, then you can focus on how it is used in your bubble sort.

Comment: As stated before, it works just when the list is 2 nodes long. I tested it with 3 nodes, with the following int values for each of them (3, 2, 1 in that order) and tried to sort them based on the value. So, Node 1: 3  Node 2: 2  node 3: 1 after sorting, the nodes are linked in the following way: Node 1: 2   Node 2: 1  Node 3: 3 . I feel that somehow it is sorting in the right way but it does not parse all the list so it is not completely sorted. Tried debugging already, but I can not get to see what the matter is. Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming that you have verified that the swap code works: what does "tried debugging" mean?  How is your code supposed to know that it is done sorting (since it may just be stopping too early)?  Which pairs of nodes does it swap, and in what sequence?

Comment: I use two nested while loops in order to sort all the list. First I parse all the list until auxiliar->next == NULL (end of the list), if there is any changes the 'flag' variable value will change to 1, if there is not it's value will still be 0 , which will stop the second while loop. To sum up, ideally it would parse the list until no changes are done. I think that the problem may be on the swap code

Comment: Thanks for explaining what I can see from your code.  If you don't want to answer any of my questions, I'll wish you good luck & leave you to it.

Comment: You asked me how does my code supposed to know that is done sorting and I answered. Concerning your other question, which pairs of nodes does it swap, I answered in my previous comment ( 3 - 2 - 1 to 2 - 1 - 3). Perhaps you missed it. Considering that I only have 500 characters to answer, it is quite understandable that I cannot completly answer your inquiries in one go (regarding sequence). If you do not know how to solve my task, it is better to let the people who do do the job. Thank you very much for your support,Scott!

Comment: "If you can, verify that your swap code works; if it doesn't, there isn't much point in going further."